# run bourne shell script with sameline export command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script something like

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./.profile
echo "sample"
```

and the .profile file has

```
export variable = xyz
```

when I run the script I get an error saying

> variable = xyz not an identifier

I know this is because of sameline export in `.profile`.

Is there a way I can make it run? I shouldn't change the sh to bash or ksh and cannot change the .profile file as it has many lines with sameline export.

Comment: Your `export` is wrong, use `export varibale="xyz"`.

Answer (score 5):

In shell-script, [spaces are not allowed in variable assignment](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html).

You should use simply:

```
export variable=xyz
```

Comment: ok...export variable=xyz....but the question is I shouldn't change the sh to bash or ksh and cannot change the .profile file as it has many lines with sameline export.....is there a way to run without getting that error

Answer (score 2):

If you have a real Bourne shell, then you have to split it into two operations:

```
variable=xyz
export variable
```

However, the number of such shells is close to vanishingly small these days — but until fairly recently at least (within the last five years, say), the `/bin/sh` on Solaris was sufficiently Bourne-shell like that you needed the two-command operation.

The Korn shell, [POSIX shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export) and Bash all support the one-command export-and-assign operation.

The line you show has problems — you can't have spaces around the assignment operator.  You claim to have written:

```
export varibale = xyz
```

You should have written:

```
export varibale=xyz
```

However, the error message would be along the lines of:

```
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
```

The complaint should be that `=` is not an identifier, not that `variable = xyz` is not a valid identifier.  I'm a little suspicious that what you quote isn't 100% accurate. As you can see, that was from `bash`, but I'd expect the same from a Bourne shell too.  If you write:

```
$ export 'variable = xyz'
-bash: export: `variable = xyz': not a valid identifier
$
```

then you get the message you claim, but I had to add the quotes around the exported 'value'.

Comment: samplefile: variable=xyz: is not an identifier...this is the exact error I get

Comment: With no spaces, it strongly indicates you have a _real_ Bourne shell and must use the separate assign-and-export notation described in the first part of my answer. Which platform are you running on?

Comment: is there a way we can avoid writing it in two different lines...I am working on unix platform

Comment: Yes: `variable=xyz; export variable` with the semicolon separating the two commands.  A few of my profile scripts still use this because they pretend to work with a real Bourne shell and I've not yet had cause to change them.  But I assume a more modern shell by default.  If you have a real Bourne shell, there is no way to avoid two separate operations — assignment and export — to create an environment variable.

Comment: ok to avoid confusion...I donot want to change my .profile as it is replicated in many different servers so changing the .profile is out of the question...

Comment: If it won't work, but you can't change it, you are pretty much out of options.  Your best bet is to get your login shell changed to `bash` or `ksh` — either will accept the `export var=value` notation.

Comment: how does changing shell to bash or ksh solve this problem ....as the script is in bourne shell(sh)

Comment: Maybe it doesn't; maybe you need to change the shebang line to specify `/bin/ksh` or `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`?  I've lost track of what your problem really is, but since what you've got does not work, something is going to have to change.